# Why is box-shadow property not working properly in SharePoint?

Tags: html, css

The Box-shadow property is not working properly in SharePoint, could you please explain why it is not working in slide share thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box-shadow property has support from IE9. Please check for the CSS property browser support.

There has an some restrictions for border-radius, box-shadow in share point . Try this I have referred from another site. They mentioned that we need to add this meta tag to specify the browser compatibility for sharepoint. `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >`

Comment: Thanks for the response, just now i have gone through the documentation.